# c# elasticsearch Unknown aggregation type [multi_terms] did you mean [rare_terms]?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Please help to solve the problem, my local environment 7.12 has no problem, but when I use AWS elasticsearch 7.10, this problem occurs. If 7.10 does not support MultiTermsAggregation, how can I adjust it?

```
     var grouRequest = new SearchRequest("log_transaction")
        {
            Size = 0,
            Query = new BoolQuery { Must = mustClauses },
            Source = false,
            TrackTotalHits = true,
            Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary
            {
                {"groupbym",new MultiTermsAggregation("groupbym")
                  {
                        Terms = new List<Term>{
                            new Term {Field = "userName.keyword" },
                            new Term {Field = "gameType.keyword" },
                            new Term {Field = "platCode.keyword" },
                        },
                       
                    Size=1000000,
                    Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary
                    {
                        {"sumbetAmount", new SumAggregation("sumbetAmount",new Field("betAmount"))},
                        {"sumwinAmount", new SumAggregation("sumwinAmount", new Field("winAmount"))},
                        {"sumeffectiveBetAmount", new SumAggregation("sumeffectiveBetAmount", new Field("effectiveBetAmount"))},
                        {"suminvalidBetAmount", new SumAggregation("suminvalidBetAmount", new Field("invalidBetAmount"))},
                        {
                          "bk_sort", new BucketSortAggregation("groupbym")
                            {
                                From=skip,
                                Size=Convert.ToInt32(model.Pagesize),
                            }
                         }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                    "stats_bucket",new CardinalityAggregation("state_count", "userName.keyword")
                }
            }
        };

        var groupResponse = _elclient.Search<ElTransactionModel>(grouRequest);
```

OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /log_transaction/_search?typed_keys=true. ServerError: Type: parsing_exception Reason: "Unknown aggregation type [multi_terms] did you mean [rare_terms]?" CausedBy: "Type: named_object_not_found_exception Reason: "[1:328] unknown field [multi_terms]